# Wordpress site resolves with :1234 after deploying to cpanel

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I have deployed a wordpress site onto cpanel and when i go to the site `http://domain.com` it resolves with `http://domain.com:1234` and gives a message that the page isn't available. I read that I can change this my going to the `wp-options` table in the database and changing the `siteurl` otpion and removing the port number from the site url.... I did this but i still get the same message. If anyone here can help me out please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tried editing the wp-config.php file did you change both the site url and home url ?

```
define('WP_HOME','http://domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://domain.com');
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I have been beating myself up about this for days!! Thanks